# Counting ways of sitting in adjacent seats

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways can $m$ people entering a theatre be seated in two rows, each containing $n$ seats with the condition that no two sit in adjacent seats in the first row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First calculate how many ways $j$ seats can be occupied from $n$: this is ${n \choose j}$ if $n\ge j$.

Then calculate how many ways $k$ seats can be occupied from $n$ with none adjacent: this is  ${n+1-k \choose k}$  if $n+1 \ge 2k$

So the answer to the original question is $$\sum_{k= \max(0,m-n)}^{\min \left(m ,\lfloor(n+1)/2\rfloor  \right)}  {n+1-k \choose k}{n \choose m-k} $$ if $2m \ge 3n+1$, and $0$ otherwise.

Multiply by $m!$ if order of the individuals matters.

Answer (score 0):

First figure out how many ways there are to choose which seats are sat in in the first place. The answers to [your earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153030/) describe useful ways of looking at that subproblem.

Then figure out, *given* any decision about which $m$ seats to use, how many ways there are to distribute the $m$ people among them. That is a standard problem.

Finally multiply the two subresults.